# Display all yet avoid repetition of DB column records in SQL Server [Moodle] [PHP]

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, moodle, moodle-api

I would like to retrieve and display values in the Database (SQL server). The only problem is that multiple records have the same value in the column. I would basically like cycle through the column and to display a list of all unique values and omit identicals.

```
$result = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE **cycle through column and list all values without duplicates**')
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it from the SQL side

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column_name) FROM table_name
```

You *could* pull all the rows back to the front end and dedupe there, but DISTINCT would probably be better performance.

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name
```

is another option.  Check your execution plan to see if it's any different in how SQL does it for performance.

Comment: The answer is correct, but in terms of performance it’s prefered a group by instead of a distinct